# Not sure I am doing this right and need help. If Column B is blank Column A should multiply by Column C. If Column B has info B need to multiply by C

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, formula

Not sure I am doing this right and need help. If Column B is blank Column A should multiply by Column C. If Column B has info B need to multiply by C

```
=IF([Column B]="IsBlank" AND, ([Column A]=!Blank), then [ColumnC]*[Column A])
IF ([Column B]=!Blank, then [ColumnC]*[Column B])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula like below for your SharePoint calculated column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Column B]),IF(ISBLANK([Column A]),"",[Column A]*[Column C]),[Column B]*[Column C])
```

**Notes**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following formula.

=IF(AND(ISBLANK([Column B]),NOT(ISBLANK([Column A]))),[Column A]*[Column C],[Column B]*[Column C])

Result:

[image]